# How to break an ajax call and redirect control to error page..?

Tags: ajax, authentication, extjs

I use MVC structure, with ExtJS as UI.

I'm implementing a filter for session check. And if session is expired I wrote in the filter.java, a redirect like response.sendRedirect("error page");

But it seems not working because, I'm triggering an ajax call everytime, and when the filter is obstructing it, it is showing that as a JS error, rather than redirecting..

Is there anyway to avoid coding in every ajax call error?? Just simply redirect, not going back to ajax error part again??

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do is a global override for a specific return code. The data connection object has a 'requestexception' event it can listen for http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax  - you could make use of that.